# Cannot read lat lon properties from geojson in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, heat-map

I have a point layer in geojson format that I am attempting to display as a leaflet heatmap:

```
$.getJSON("newmap.geojson", function(data) {

           coords = [];

        L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng);

            },
             onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                coords.push(feature.geometry.coordinates);
            },
            coordsToLatLng: function (coords) {
            return new L.heatLayer(coords);
            }

        }).addTo(map);
        });
```

The map appears, but I receive an error in the console that reads : `Cannot read property 'lat' of null`

I have tried to change `coords.push(feature.geometry.coordinates);` to `coords.push([feature.geometry.coordinates[1],feature.geometry.coordinates[0]]);` but this produces the same error.

Is there something I am doing wrong in the reading in the geojson file or is there a known workaround ?

EDIT: the first lines of my geojson file, which is a feature collection, look like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "st_x": 19.952030181884801, "st_y": 50.055513141929701 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 19.952030181884801, 50.055513141929701 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "st_x": 18.672015, "st_y": 50.287181666666697 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 18.672015, 50.287181666666697 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "st_x": 18.671918333333299, "st_y": 50.28722 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 18.671918333333299, 50.28722 ] } },
```

Comment: How does your GeoJSON look like? Are you fully sure it only has points? What's the value of `coords` when calling `L.heatLayer`? Are you aware that you have a variable called `coords` in different scopes in the same code? (the last one is not only confusing, but prone to errors)

Comment: I've added the GeoJSON structure to the question

Comment: Check your GeoJSON here http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: It is valid as I am able to apply the clustering function to the points

Comment: Have a look at the last comment from Jmuccigr https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/issues/64
Maybe it helps.

Comment: This code produces no errors, but still no heatmap is appearing, why? : `var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("newmap.geojson");

var heat = L.heatLayer(geojsonLayer).addTo(map);`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to parseFloat() the coords values:

```
   coords.push( parseFloat(feature.geometry.coordinates[1]), parseFloat(feature.geometry.coordinates[0]))
```

Inspired by the comments [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/issues/12).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `L.geoJson` object to display the `L.heatLayer`. You have to convert the GeoJSON to a serie of coordinates. The code below should do the job to transform your GeoJSON to the expect input format of `L.heatLayer`, create the layer and add it to the map

```
$.getJSON("newmap.geojson", function(data) {
   coords = data.features.map(feat => feat.geometry.coordinates.slice().reverse())
   var heat = L.heatLayer(coords).addTo(map);
});
```